# res.redirect doesn't change page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I'm trying to make a login system to redirect the page from the login page to the Home page if the details are true and Some why the server gets the **GET** but does not redirect to homepage...

Here the Express Code:

```
router.post('/login',  async (req,res, next) => {
    try{    

       let usersData = await  getFiles(__dirname + '/users.json');
       let parsedUsers = JSON.parse(usersData);
       let userChecker;
       let passwordChecker;
       for(let i = 0; i < parsedUsers.length; i++){
       if(parsedUsers[i].userName === req.body.userName){
           userChecker = true;
           passwordChecker = parsedUsers[i].password
           break;
       } 
       }

       if(!userChecker){
        console.log(`${req.body.userName} Not exist`);
    }
        else if(!bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, passwordChecker)){
           console.log('Pass is wrong');
       }
        else {
        console.log(`${req.body.userName} Approved`);
        res.redirect( 301  ,'/')
       }
        }
     catch (err) {
      if(err) throw err
    };
})
```

Here is the app request :

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log('Arrived to Homepage ')

})
```

Server console is printing **"Arrived to Homepage"** but the page itself doen't change to homepage from login page.

React:

```
class Main extends Component {
    render() {
        return (

            <div className="Main">
            <Switch>
            <Route exact path ='/' component={Homepage} />
            </Switch>
            </div>
   )
    }
}
```

Comment: `res.redirect` is not the same thing as internal React routing

Comment: @kinduser then what is it doing? should I try to change link with React instead?

Comment: AFAIK to handle redirects from server side, you need to add a StaticRouter (`react-router`, not `react-router-dom`)

Comment: Do you use react-router?

Comment: @Trace Yes, and I know how to use the <LINK> but what if the details are wrong? how would I Prevent <LINK> from running?

Comment: Yeah it won't be working because your `app.get('/', (req, res) => {}` is empty. Shouldn't you be doing your SSR rendering and StaticRouter setup here?